# react-native : How to show collabsible on top of a view

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using [react-native-collapsible](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible) and it works well but I need the collapsible view to show on top of my `flatlist`.

When I use `collapsible` view it will `push down my flatlist`. I want to see my collapsible view on top of my `flatlist`

This is my collapsible view:

```
collapsibleView() {
    return (
      <Collapsible collapsed={!this.state.collapsed}>
        <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            alignItems: 'flex-end',
            paddingRight: 10,
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              marginTop: 10,
              width: 68,
              height: 134,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              shadowColor: 'black',
              shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
              shadowOpacity: 0.2,
              shadowRadius: 2,
              marginBottom: 2,
              borderRadius: 4,
            }}>
            <ScrollView>
              <CollapsibleStyle style={styles.popupMonth} text="8월" />
              <CollapsibleStyle style={styles.popupMonth} text="9월" />
              <CollapsibleStyle style={styles.popupMonth} text="10월" />
              <CollapsibleStyle style={styles.popupMonth} text="11월" />
              <CollapsibleStyle style={styles.popupMonth} text="12월" />
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Collapsible>
    );
  }
```

In this is my code with flatlist:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.customHeaderHandler()}
        {this.collapsibleView()}
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

My view will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to give this style to a flat list.

```
style={{top: 0}}
```

Or add parent view to flatlist and same style property.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I tried both and it won't work.